# Tracking file changes from Photoshop with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

I'm currently working on a component of my application which monitors a specific directory for files and keeps them in a DB together with special metadata of those files.

I use a FileSystemWatcher to track additions, renaming, deletion and changes to those files / directories. So far this works perfectly fine. But since FileSystemWatcher is not capable of tracking movements, I'm using hashes to keep track of the files.

Now in order to keep this working I must update the hash in the database once a file was changed. But my first test was proof of failure. Photoshop obviously has some tricky ways to save a file. I always catch a "psXXXXX.tmp" file being changed which I filter with the FileAttributes.Archive. The problem is: The watcher does not throw again for the real changed file. Since I need the real filename and not the temporary one, I can't update the DB.

Even if the file changes in size or the write time changed - nothing happens. It gets completely ignored. The event rises once when the temporary file gets created (or the original the renamed, I don't know) and then nothing happens anymore.

Can anybody explain this behaviour? Has anybody an idea how to avoid this?
Any workarounds or other solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Photoshop certainly is special; I notice that when I update a file on my desktop with PS, it always resets its position as if it were not updated but created (which probably is what happens..) It also has a nasty way of sitting on file locks.. - Do you watch all events?

Comment: I found an issue on MS Connect which was related to Word. There one of the MS guys said that Word renames the original file. I tried this out and found out, that Photoshop does this too. I check in the "Rename" event of the watcher for the condition that the "OldName" ends with ".tmp". This is a bad approach since not every program must use .tmp as ending, but I guess it applies to all major products. And if not, I may have to check for other ones, too. Sadly the watcher is really badly when it comes to changes or movements.

Comment: One thing to reckon with is that many seemingly atomic operations are in fact not but consist of several separate operations, all of which trigger a FSW event.  so I guess the 'changed' file is in fact created fresh and the old temp version finally deleted.. which means at the very least 3 for 1, maybe more..

Comment: The Changed event gets risen once the .tmp-file was written and the Rename event when the .tmp was renamed to the original file's name. I don't know what exactly happens, but these are the only events which get fired. All in all enough, but far from nice.

Comment: I removed the database and firebird tags as your actual question is not related to these tags (you might use a database/firebird in your solution, but your question is about filesystemwatcher).

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem with PS, I only had to add:

```
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

and all was good.

Comment: Well I eventually went with a filter driver. The `FileSystemWatcher` sadly is a bit inaccurate at times and did miss a lot of files when copying lots of files fast. The filter driver gets every change with a 100% coverage which suits me very well. For my scenario I do need full reliability.